# Using partial template under view root

Tags: templates, grails, gsp

I have a partial template I'm including in my `main.gsp`.

This partial content will be slightly differnt for each controller/page on the site.
Therefore I will have a seperate `_headerDetails.gsp` for each view directory.

This works fine except for the default application `index.gsp`.
When I include a `_headerDetails.gsp` under root view directory I get the following error:

```
org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.pages.exceptions.GroovyPagesException: Error processing GroovyPageView: Template not found for name [headerDetails] and path [//_headerDetails.gsp]
```

Does grails not allow partials in the root directory?

**Main.gsp**

```
<html>
    <head>
        <g:layoutTitle/>
        <r:layoutResources/>
        <link href="${resource(dir: 'css', file: 'style.css')}" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet">
    </head>

    <body class="home">

        <div id="wrapper">

            <div id="page_top"></div>

            <div id="content">
                <g:render template="/common/header" />

                <g:render template="headerDetails" />

                <br class="clear" />

                <g:layoutBody/>

                <br class="clear" />

            </div>

            <div id="page_bottom"></div>

            <g:render template="/common/footer" />  

        </div>

        <r:layoutResources/>

   </body>
</html>
```

Comment: This question, and its answer, helped me.  Fail to see how it is "Too Localized". Thanks anyway for over-moderation.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

is it `headDetails` or `headerDetails`??

if its not a typo issue, try using a `/` before the template name to get to the root dir!

Comment: That's a typo I've fixed gotomanners. Figured out the problem, see answer. Your answer half fixes my issue, thanks.

Comment: Prefixing with the slash worked fine for me, thanks

Answer (score 3):

```
<g:if test="${params.action.equals('')}">
  <g:render template="/headerDetails" />
</g:if>  
<g:else>
  <g:render template="headerDetails" />
</g:else>
```

Answer (score 1):

See chapter "Template basics > Shared templates" of the grails docs:

http://grails.org/doc/2.0.x/guide/theWebLayer.html#viewsAndTemplates

> In this case you can place them in the root views directory at
>   `grails-app/views` or any subdirectory below that location, and then
>   with the template attribute use an absolute location starting with `/`
>   instead of a relative location. For example if you had a template
>   called `grails-app/views/shared/_mySharedTemplate.gsp`, you would
>   reference it as:
>
> ```
> <g:render template="/shared/mySharedTemplate" />
> ```